# Using python how to uncompress files with spark?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, pyspark, aws-glue

```
def compress():
    if args['compression'] == 'Yes':

        for day in getdate():
            x = str(day.strftime('%Y/%m/%d')).replace("/0","/")
            print (x)

            loc_postfix = log_type+"/"+x
            location = "s3://bucket/rawfiles/"+loc_postfix+"/*"
            compressed_path = "s3://bucket/compressfiles/"+loc_postfix+""
            rawfile = spark.read.text(location).repartition(partitions)
            rawfile.write.text(compressed_path, compression="bzip2")
```

This is my code for compressing files but now I'm trying to figure out using spark how to uncompress files. To compress I read files from the rawfiles folder which is partitioned by year/month/day then compress to bz2 with partitioning (this just creates a specified number of files as bz2 ex: 100 files partitioned by 20 will give 20 bz2 files). This code is run in a glue job.

Comment: what needs to decompress them?  Spark should detect that files are compressed and you don't need to do anything explicit in your code to decompress them.  Do you have some sort of code that isn't working?

Answer (score 1):

`spark.read` should handle compressed files automatically, you don't need to decompress them before read.